# Laravel: Choose the right relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have `users` table and each user can add friends. friends are other users.

I created a pivot table named `user_friends` with the following columns:

```
id | user_id | friend_id
```

How I can define a relationship so I can get user friends using `$user->friends()`?

Comment: The most important thing is to ensure your pivot table name is in alphabetical order with singular table names. Pivot table must be "friend_user".

Answer (score 0):

First: a pivot table doesn't have id for rows

You need to have a table friend_user

```
 friend_id | user_id
```

Setup your relationships in User model

```
public function friends()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

I am not 100% sure if this will work, but would like to know if it does!

Comment: Why the second function?

Comment: @TheUnreal I think you should explicitly put the name of the pivotable as a second parameter of the hasMany function. Then it will work. The second function is not necessary.

Comment: @JohnDoe when I put the name of the pivottable as second parameter it tries to look for it as a column , `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.user_friends' `

Comment: @TheUnreal normally laravel looks for the pivot table by using the names of the models related. However you can pass the pivot table name as an argument, as you can do with the related fields. You can define them like this: `return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'friends_user', 
      'user_id', 'friend_id');`

Comment: happy to help. also for your information you can add more columns to the pivot table, including an autoincrement id using `withPivot()` method in the relationship, specifying as parameters the extra fields. You can create the pivot fields using migrations and then you just update the parameters in the `withPivot()` method.

Comment: @TheUnreal in answer to you question about the second function, it is good practice to have the reverse of the relationship available so that in the context of a `Friend` you can return their associated users and from a `User` context you can return their friends. It makes a bit more sense when you have distinct models for each but not so much in this case!

Comment: @xhulio Thanks, but what if I want to add a new friend to user? how I can do that?

Comment: you can do it by getting the friend collection like `$friend = User::where('id', $friend_id)->first(); $user = *Get Current logged in User*; $user->friends()->attach($friend);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as following:

In your Users class define following function to get friends of specific user:

```
public function friends()
{
   return $this->hasMany("App\Friends","user_id","id");
}

$user = Users::find($user_id);
$user_friends = $user->friends()->get();
```